# Get nested value in array based on condition for another value in that array

Tags: node.js, filtering, lodash

I had difficulty creating a title for this question…

Say I have data like this:

```
{"total_results":78,"resources":[{"metadata":{"verified_at":"2018-10-17T21:07:43.935Z","linkages":[{"origin":"ABC","id":"a"},{"origin":"XYZ","id":"b"}]}},{"metadata":{"verified_at":"2018-10-17T21:07:43.935Z","linkages":[{"origin":"ABC","id":"c"},{"origin":"XYZ","id":"d"}]}}]}
```

Consider the `resources` field. I want to output an array that includes an `id` for each array element. To get the ID, go to the linkages field, which is an array, and find the element that has `"origin": "ABC"`. The `id` field in that element is the ID that should be returned.

This code snippet works, but it seems too verbose. There must be an easier way.

```
_.map(_.filter(_.flatten(_.map(body.resources, 'metadata.linkages')),['origin','ABC']), 'id')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```js
var data = { "total_results": 78, "resources": [ { "metadata": { "verified_at": "2018-10-17T21:07:43.935Z", "linkages": [{ "origin": "ABC", "id": "a" }, { "origin": "XYZ", "id": "b" }] } }, { "metadata": { "verified_at": "2018-10-17T21:07:43.935Z", "linkages": [{ "origin": "ABC", "id": "c" }, { "origin": "XYZ", "id": "d" }] } } ] }

 const result = _(data.resources)
  .flatMap('metadata.linkages')
  .filter(['origin', 'ABC'])
  .map('id')
  .value()
 
console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

With chaining and [**flatMap**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#flatMap) + [filter](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#filter) & [map](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#map)

Another approach would be with `flatMap` & `reduce`:

```js
var data = { "total_results": 78, "resources": [ { "metadata": { "verified_at": "2018-10-17T21:07:43.935Z", "linkages": [{ "origin": "ABC", "id": "a" }, { "origin": "XYZ", "id": "b" }] } }, { "metadata": { "verified_at": "2018-10-17T21:07:43.935Z", "linkages": [{ "origin": "ABC", "id": "c" }, { "origin": "XYZ", "id": "d" }] } } ] }

const result = _(data.resources)
  .flatMap('metadata.linkages')
  .reduce((r,c) => (_.isEqual(c.origin, 'ABC') ? r.push(c.id) : null, r), [])

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Another more concise version:

```js
var data = { "total_results": 78, "resources": [{ "metadata": { "verified_at": "2018-10-17T21:07:43.935Z", "linkages": [{ "origin": "ABC", "id": "a" }, { "origin": "XYZ", "id": "b" }] } }, { "metadata": { "verified_at": "2018-10-17T21:07:43.935Z", "linkages": [{ "origin": "ABC", "id": "c" }, { "origin": "XYZ", "id": "d" }] } }] }

const result = _.reduce(data.resources, (r,c) => 
   (r.push(_.find(c.metadata.linkages, {origin: 'ABC'}).id), r), [])

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

With ES6 you can go with something like this:

```js
var data = { "total_results": 78, "resources": [{ "metadata": { "verified_at": "2018-10-17T21:07:43.935Z", "linkages": [{ "origin": "ABC", "id": "a" }, { "origin": "XYZ", "id": "b" }] } }, { "metadata": { "verified_at": "2018-10-17T21:07:43.935Z", "linkages": [{ "origin": "ABC", "id": "c" }, { "origin": "XYZ", "id": "d" }] } }] }

const result = data.resources.reduce((r,c) => 
   (r.push(c.metadata.linkages.find(x => x.origin == 'ABC').id), r), [])

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Wish it could be more succinct, but `flatMap` was a good suggestion that cuts out one function call.